# How to configure NetBeans to be able to debug Tomcat 8?

Tags: tomcat, netbeans, tomcat8

Can't find any settings for enabling debugging mode in Tomcat 8 so I can attach breakpoints from NetBeans. 
Somebody have some experience with this. On Apache web site is example for Tomcat 7 but i do not have same config files in 8.

I used installation mode not standalone for Tomcat 8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tomcat does not require any debugging options in order to use debugging from NetBeans. You may have to configure NetBeans correctly in order to launch Tomcat in debugging mode, but Tomcat itself does not need any configuration to do that.